# Jquery mobile pages not loading unless i refresh

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-app-engine

I successfully upload my app to Google App Engine, but when ever i want to perform an operation `(GET/POST)` from a page, it doesn't work unless i manually refresh the page.

This is my messy project structure:

[image]

The `index.html` file (called by `/main`) is the first page that loads, and that file is in the `templates` directory.All other files (html and .js) are located in a separate directory called `html`. Sensing that this might be the cause, i added these scripts to my index.html file:

```
  <script src="/html/js/registration.js"></script>
  <script src="/html/js/profile-page.js"></script>
```

without luck.
Also, a the top of the `profile-page.html` and `registration.html` files are their corresponding `.js` files.

If i enter data into the registration page, it doesn't get posted to the server,but if i refresh the page before entering the data, it works.Same thing with the profile page which displays the data i entered.

**App.yaml: **

```
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /js/(.*\.js)
  mime_type: application/javascript
  static_files: js/\1
  upload: js/(.*\.js)

- url: /images
  static_dir: images

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /html
  static_dir: html

- url: .*
    script: main.app

libraries:
 - name: webapp2
   version: "2.5.2"
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head lang="en">
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="/html/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="/html/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="/html/js/profile-page.js"></script>
<script src="/html/js/team-members-view.js"></script>
<script src="/html/js/view-teams.js"></script>
<script src="/html/js/registration.js"></script>
<script src="/html/js/daily-activities.js"></script>
<script src="/html/js/choose-team.js"></script>


<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="home">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
    <h1> Home </h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <img src="/html/images/logo.jpg" width="450" height="300"/>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="/html/registration-page.html" id="home-to-reg-button">Click your      to register</a></li>
        <li><a href="/html/profile-page.html">View Your Profile</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
    <h3>&#169; </h3>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**MainHandler:**

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/index.html', {}))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([

('/', MainHandler),
('/uploadNewMember', MemberRegistrationHandler),
('/profileView', MemberDetailsHandler)
 ], debug=True)
```

Comment: Directory  structure will tell us little without seeing your app.yaml and probably your main handler and index.html.  At least the important parts.

Comment: Hi @TimHoffman, i just updated the question to show these.

Comment: If you view the developer console in the browser, are you seeing any "404 - Not Found"s?  Or, AFTER you post, can you refresh the page and see if it shows up?  It may be a matter of eventual consistency, where it takes a few seconds to post to the datastore, and your page reloads too quickly to find it.  Post, wait, refresh.  Is it there?

Comment: There is no communication with the datastore whatsoever unless I refresh every page I visit.

Comment: I still don't understand exactly what you are saying.  Are you saying that if you go to mysite.com/ (a GET), and enter data in a form (a POST), that the data does not get handled?  But, if you go to mysite.com/ and then hit refresh (another GET), then enter data, that it works as designed?  Where is your POST handler?

Comment: Yes,the data does not get handled unless I refresh the page.mysite.com/ takes me to a main page,on that home page I have a button to the registration page and profile page.Unless I refresh the registration page,nothing I enter in it gets sent and unless I refresh the profile page,nothing gets returned from the server.